# Error Handling in LC-3?

Tags: lc3

I have this question on my review sheet that I cant seem to get but rather than ask you for the answer I would rather like to learn the difference between these specific concepts.

For reference the question is  An LC-3 instruction ADD R1,R2, #45 produces an error. It will be caught at a. assembly time b. link time c. run time d. compile time. Rather than just finding out the answer what  would rather like to know is what is the difference between these and how do they differ when it comes to error handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the C programming language as an example the 4 steps to create an executable program Preprocessing, Compiling, Assembling, and Linking.

### Compile time

These are generally common and are caused by a malformed user program that the compiler can't process, things such as forgetting a semicolon can cause a compiler error.

### Assembly Time

Something went wrong with the assembler.  This includes using instructions incorrectly as above, not defining a LABEL but using it in an instruction etc.

### Link Time

As part of the C compile process to form an executable many object files generated by the assemble step are linked together.  In C programming you can specify that some symbol is defined externally via the extern keyword, other things like function prototypes will tell the compiler a function is defined somewhere.

The linker will resolve where those variables/functions live.  If you haven't declared a function/variable and something references it then you will get a undefined reference error.  Same for if something is defined multiple times.

### Run Time

An error occurred during running your program, this is something such as accessing a pointer that is null, or dividing by zero.